# React Native fetch not working for a specific URL

Tags: fetch, react-native, react-native-ios

URL : `http://10.10.1.23:8085/LdapServices/ldapservice/signUp`

Body:

```
{ 
        "cn": " ",
        "sn": "abcd",
        "uid": "123123123",
        "userPassword": "test123",
        "applicationName":"app1"
}
```

> The above request is working perfectly from POSTMAN (Content-Type: application/json) and I'm getting
>   the response properly.

```
fetch("http://10.10.1.23:8085/LdapServices/ldapservice/signUp", {  
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        cn              : "",
        sn              : "abcd",
        uid             : "123123123",
        userPassword    : "test123",
        applicationName : "app1"
      })
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      console.log(responseJson)      
    })
    .catch((error) => {      
      console.error(error);
    });
```

> But when I use it like this from my react native application, its not
>   giving any response. And after waiting for a long time I'm getting
>   "Network request failed" message. Application is working fine when
>   using any other URLs.

Comment: Have u tried without `body: JSON.stringify(...)`?

Comment: No I tried this way.

Comment: Please try with `body: {...}`, just plain object.

Comment: getting an error. "Unsupported BodyInit type"

Comment: Other requests from your app do work though, right?
Also, just curious, why that url, doesn't `localhost` on your machine translate to `10.0.2.2` for avd?

Comment: Maybe if you are running this on iOS, it wouldn't open because is a http instead of https, try it in android emulator

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai I'm running it in android.\

Comment: @flaky I've tried with localhost. Its showing "network request failed" message immediately on button press. when I tried with ip address the error message is showing after waiting for a long time.

Comment: @unknown123: ok, but other request do work with that ip?
yeah, `localhost` won't work - but `10.0.2.2` is a 'Special alias to your host loopback interface (i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your development machine)' that's why I asked about that weird url.

Probably need a bit more info to work with this here

Comment: I called 3 web services from the same page. 2 of them were worked properly. this is the only service which is running on my machine. Others were running on some remote systems.